# Errors of installing VMware-tools

Tags: vmware, shared-folders, vmware-fusion, vmware-tools

Previously, I post a question about an error of installing VMware-tools in a Ubuntu under a virtual machine. I have not got any solution yet.

So I installed another `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` under the virtual machine. Everything was new. I did software updates, and then directly tried to install VMware-tools. I have got an error, always about the shared folder. The whole log is here:

http://pastebin.com/gPtki9Uq

This problem of shared folder really is killing me... Hope someone could help...

PS: I use `OS X 10.9.2` and a virtual machine `6.0.5 VMware Fusion`.

PPS: I guess something has been written to some files of VMware Fusion, I would need to reset that or overwrite that. Unfortunately, I could not reinstall VMware Fusion (because I have Windows and other things inside).

Comment: Can you upload your vmware-tools virtual cd?

Comment: Did the answer work? Any feedback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be a missing or an erroneous declaration / erroneous call of the function `vfs_readlink()` in `HgfsReadLink()`  in `link.c`:

```
/tmp/modconfig-NAS1rK/vmhgfs-only/link.c: In function ‘HgfsReadlink’:
/tmp/modconfig-NAS1rK/vmhgfs-only/link.c:186:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vfs_readlink’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

This might be fixed by editing one of the header files included in `link.c` or by editing `link.c` itself, but the easiest (and probably fastest) way would be to just patch the faulty file. There's this patcher around which between other `vmware-tools` bugs also specifically addresses your issue: [Github.com: vmware-tools-patches](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches).

I've checked the patches included and I found out that between those included specifically for your version of `vmware-tools` (`9.6.2`) two of them affect the offending function over two different kernels (`04-vmblock-vfs_readlink-kernel-3.15-tools-9.6.2.patch` > kernel 3.15 and `10-vmhgfs-vfs_readlink-kernel-3.16-tools-9.6.2.patch` > kernel 3.16).

Since the `vmware-tools` installer you used messes with kernel modules, and since as you suggested some files probably have been written already during the previous attempt to install, considering furthermore that you have just reinstalled the system, instead of going through unnecessary headaches i highly suggest you to clean reinstall `Ubuntu` on the virtual machine once again before running the patcher and installing `vmware-tools` again.

**Inside the virtual machine**:

1. Download and install `git`: `sudo apt-get install git`
2. Download the patcher/patches somewhere, let's say in `~/`: `cd ~/ && git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git`
3. Move the `vmware-tools` tarball to `~/vmware-tools-patches`: `cp ~/Downloads/<vmware_tools_tarball_name> ~/vmware-tools-patches`
4. Run the patcher: `cd vmware-tools-patches && ./untar-and-patch.sh`
5. Install `vmware-tools`: `./compile.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Take the easy way!

The software you are using to virtualize is now outdated.

Download VirtualBox and install Virtualbox tools and you will find your problem solved.

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

There is always a non free alternative called Parallels for Mac that does all the work for you, it will install Ubuntu 14.04 with everything you need, it also has other options such as Android and Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

If do you want to archieve a shared folders like behavior without installing `vmware-tools` you can enable SSH on OS X in the system settings, as shown in the image.

[image: Enable SSH]

Then, in the guest machine do this:

- Open a Nautilus (a.k.a File Manager) window.
- Click on `Connect to Server` as seen in the picture.

  [image: Connect to server]
- Type `sftp://YOUR_MAC_HOSTNAME` in the dialog that pops up (where `YOUR_MAC_HOSTNAME` is the text that comes in the "Computer Name" field of your OS X Sharing configuration)
- Press enter
- If all is ok, you will be browsing your OS X filesystem.

Comment: The proposed solution will wokr only in one way: from `Ubuntu VM` to the `Mac OS` host. If you want to copy some files to the host OS you have to use the guest VM and copy them to the host. Shared folders doesn't require this.